# checkstyle: disable ++ warning

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I recently installed the checkstyle addon for eclipse, while it does help me make some parts of my code clearer, there are some stupid rules.
I've been capable of disabling most of those besides the using ++ is not allowed rule.
Does anyone have any idea how I can disable that one?

Answer (score 2):

It is in "[**Coding Problems / Illegal Token**](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalToken)" (or "Illegal Token Text")

In the setting of that Token check, you will find the "Postfix increment operator ++" for you to un-check.